# How to render an observables arrays length in template Angular 2

Tags: json, angular, typescript, rxjs, angular2-template

I have an observable of my created object type 'ICase'. This observable is used to retrieve data from a JSON file using this method. This method is in a service file.

---template-service.ts---

```
 private _caseUrl = 'api/cases.json';
getCases(): Observable<ICase[]> 
    {    
            return this._http.get(this._caseUrl)
            .map((response: Response) => <ICase[]> response.json())
            .do(data => console.log('All: ' + JSON.stringify(data)))
            .catch(this.handleError);     
    }
```

However in the template I want to display the length of my observable array. I have tried using the async pipe and using the .length operator but I can't seem to display this in the dom.

----template.component.ts ----

```
  ngOnInit(): void
{
    console.log("---In OnInit---");
    this._templateService.getCases()
    .subscribe(cases => this.cases = cases, error=> this.errorMessage = <any>error);
     console.log('Num of cases: ' + this._templateService.getCases().map.length);
      //  this.count =  this._templateService.getCases.length;

}
```

As you can see from my html, I can display the observable elements ok, although I have hidden the data for confidentiality reasons. The red circles indicate where I am trying to display the observables length.
[Browser Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ZkzS.jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best thing that you could do is use the `async` pipe. For example:

```
// in template.component.ts
  data$:Observable<ICase[]>;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.data$ = this._templateService.getCases();
}

//in template.component.html
<ng-container *ngIf="data$ | async as data">
   {{data.length}}
   <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let item of data">
            {{item}}
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
</ng-container>
```

But beware, in this approach Im not considering error handling.

(I havent tried it but it should work :D )

Comment: You did it! You absolute legend! Been trying that all day!

Answer (score 0):

Since you're working with observables you have to subscribe to them to start retrieving any data. Before you do this it is just a definition of what to do with the data.

This is one approach: Use `.do` to add a hook to the observable that is able to access the data.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this._templateService.getCases()
    .do((cases) => {
      console.log("Number of cases:", cases.length);
    })
    .subscribe(cases => { this.cases = cases; },
               error => { this.errorMessage = error as any; }
    );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response but it gives me a load of errors unless I change the code from (cases.map(case => case.length)  to (cases.map(cases => cases.length). Then I only have one error which says property 'length' does not exist on type 'ICase'

Comment: I'm sorry - I meant `cases =>` and misunderstood your example. Let me adjust my post.

Comment: Everything seemed to be working fine, but I have an error in the console window with ERROR TypeError: error.json is not a function
    at CatchSubscriber.TemplateService.handleError [as selector] (app/template/template-service.js:39)

Comment: That looks like a separate issue. Your `handleError` is probably expecting the response to be one coming from `_http` so edit that function to print `error` and not `error.json`.

Comment: Just as FYI - the style guide for angular [recommends against underscores](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#style-03-04) in private properties.

Comment: Another error is logged to the system. SyntaxError: Unexpected token / in JSON at position 248
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Response.Body.json (body.ts:36)
    at MapSubscriber.eval [as project] (template-service.ts:26)
    at MapSubscriber._next (map.ts:75)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.ts:95)
    at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (xhr_backend.ts:104)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:424)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (ng_zone.ts:253)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:423)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:191)

Comment: Again, unrelated to your original question. Just check the JSON output of your API call.